# HBase JAVA API fails creating a table

Tags: hbase, create-table

I've been trying to create a simple table with Java Api, but has not been able to do it. I will try to explain the whole process in case anybody can help me.

First of all I have downloaded the version 1.2.1 from  http://apache.rediris.es/hbase/1.2.1/hbase-1.2.1-bin.tar.gz on my ubuntu machine.

Once unzip I have modified the hbase-site file with the following paths:

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>hbase.rootdir</name>
<value>file:///home/XXXXX/hbase</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
<value>/home/XXXX/zookeeper</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Then I have started the service using start-hbase.sh and using the jps command I have verified that the process is running:

```
7734 HMaster
8614 Jps
```

Then I have launched the shell hbase shell and created a table and verified that the table exists.

```
hbase(main):001:0> create 'table1', 'colfam1', 'colfam2'
0 row(s) in 1.6920 seconds
=> Hbase::Table - table1
hbase(main):002:0> list
TABLE                                                              
table1                                                                  
1 row(s) in 0.0410 seconds
=> ["table1"]
```

Once everything seems to be working on console mode, I have tried to do the same using the Java API.

This is my code of CreateTable.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HColumnDescriptor;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Admin;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Connection;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;

public class HBaseCreateTable {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       // Instantiating configuration class
       Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        Connection conn =ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);
        Admin admin = conn.getAdmin();

       // Instantiating table descriptor class
      HTableDescriptor tableDescriptor = new HTableDescriptor(TableName.valueOf("emp"));

   // Adding column families to table descriptor
   tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("personal"));
   tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("professional"));

   // Execute the table through admin
   System.out.println(" Creating the table ");
   admin.createTable(tableDescriptor);
   System.out.println(" Table created ");
   }
  }
```

Once the file has been created, I have created a class file using the following command:

```
javac -classpath /home/XXXX/example/lib/hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar:/home/XXXX/hbase/lib/* CreateTable.java
```

As you can see I'm using the hbase jars and more over I have downloaded another jar file

```
wget http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-core/1.2.1/hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar
```

Finally I have launched the java code:

```
java -classpath /home/XXXX/example/lib/hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar:/home/XXXX/hbase/lib/*:. CreateTable
```

As a result I get the following log

```
16/05/07 12:49:34 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Process identifier=hconnection-0xd9cbc24 connecting to ZooKeeper ensemble=localhost:2181
16/05/07 12:49:34 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.6-1569965, built on 02/20/2014 09:09 GMT
16/05/07 12:49:34 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:host.name=XXX
16/05/07 12:49:34 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.version=1.7.0_65
16/05/07 12:49:34 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
16/05/07 12:49:34 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
16/05/07 12:49:34 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.class.path=/home/XXX/example/lib/hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/xom-1.2.5.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/jcodings-1.0.8.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/hadoop-auth-2.5.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.5.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/jamon-runtime-2.4.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.5.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/asm-3.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/xml-apis-1.3.03.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/hadoop-hdfs-2.5.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/guava-12.0.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/jettison-1.3.3.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/hbase-external-blockcache-1.2.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/hbase-common-1.2.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/jersey-client-1.9.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/hbase-hadoop2-compat-1.2.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/hbase-it-1.2.1-tests.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/hbase-protocol-1.2.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.5.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/hbase-annotations-1.2.1-tests.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/joni-2.1.2.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/hbase-examples-1.2.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/hbase-thrift-1.2.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/xalan-2.7.0.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/hbase-common-1.2.1-tests.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/jets3t-0.9.0.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/commons-math-2.2.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.7.0.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/hbase-hadoop-compat-1.2.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/hbase-server-1.2.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/hadoop-yarn-api-2.5.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/bsh-core-2.0b4.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/hbase-rest-1.2.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/hbase-server-1.2.1-tests.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/antisamy-1.4.3.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/hbase-client-1.2.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.5.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/findbugs-annotations-1.3.9-1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/httpcore-4.4.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.5.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/batik-ext-1.7.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/batik-css-1.7.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/batik-util-1.7.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/commons-codec-1.9.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/esapi-2.1.0.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/commons-fileupload-1.2.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/hadoop-yarn-client-2.5.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/hadoop-common-2.5.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/hbase-resource-bundle-1.2.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/libthrift-0.9.3.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/hbase-prefix-tree-1.2.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.13.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/xml-apis-ext-1.3.04.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/httpclient-4.2.5.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/hadoop-client-2.5.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/jsp-api-2.1-6.1.14.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/spymemcached-2.11.6.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.5.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/junit-4.12.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/hbase-it-1.2.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/hbase-procedure-1.2.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/disruptor-3.3.0.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/hbase-shell-1.2.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/nekohtml-1.9.12.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/hbase-annotations-1.2.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.5.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/jetty-sslengine-6.1.26.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/home/XXX/hbase/lib/hadoop-yarn-common-2.5.1.jar:.
16/05/07 12:49:34 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
16/05/07 12:49:34 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
16/05/07 12:49:34 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
16/05/07 12:49:34 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Linux
16/05/07 12:49:34 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=amd64
16/05/07 12:49:34 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=3.13.0-32-generic
16/05/07 12:49:34 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=XXX
16/05/07 12:49:34 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/home/XXX
16/05/07 12:49:34 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/home/XXX/example
16/05/07 12:49:34 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=hconnection-0xd9cbc240x0, quorum=localhost:2181, baseZNode=/hbase
16/05/07 12:49:34 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
16/05/07 12:49:34 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
16/05/07 12:49:34 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x1548aa96e9b0012, negotiated timeout = 40000
Creating the table
16/05/07 12:50:23 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=10, retries=35, started=48777 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
16/05/07 12:50:43 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=11, retries=35, started=68849 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
16/05/07 12:51:03 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=12, retries=35, started=88997 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
16/05/07 12:51:23 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=13, retries=35, started=109114 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
16/05/07 12:51:44 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=14, retries=35, started=129260 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
```

As you can see at the end, the code ends at the table creation and an info message appears

```
   System.out.println(" Creating the table ");
   admin.createTable(tableDescriptor);
   System.out.println(" Table created ");

Creating the table
16/05/07 12:50:23 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=10, retries=35, started=48777 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving some pointers since I was not able to give  sharp shoot answer for this.

- Since you are able to create a table using shell and  through java client you are not able to, You can also do something like this:

  ```
  export HBASE_CLASSPATH= `hbase classpath`
  ```

  I would suggest to use java -classpath $HBASE_CLASSPATH .
- Generally these are errors from zookeeper. please check zookeeper quorum/connecting to zkcli command

Comment: I have restarted the machine and now it works correctly. I don't understand where the problem was. Anyway, thanks for yuour help RamPrasad.

Comment: In general, Its not recommended to restart Hbase (unless its last step if its too obscure to find) to fix issues. especially if its production system, where multiple jobs are running. we need to find the root cause and fix it. there are some hbase adminstration commands like hbck (http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/hbck.in.depth.html) and there is trouble shooting guide(http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/trouble.html)