# Creation of table in Hbase using Java API

Tags: java, hbase

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HColumnDescriptor;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin;

public class CreateTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Configuration con = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        HBaseAdmin admin = new HBaseAdmin(con);

        HTableDescriptor ht = new HTableDescriptor("emp");

        ht.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("add"));
        ht.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("dept"));

        admin.createTable(ht);

        System.out.println("Table Created");
    }
}
```

I have used the above code to create Hbase table. I have downloaded all the Jars which are required and added them as an when am getting errors. But still am getting lots of errors related to zookeeper.
My doubt is, do I have to Zookeeper connection using JAVA API before creating the table. And am using JDK 1.8
Please guide me the exact procedure in creating the table in Hbase using JAVA API. These are the below errors am getting with Zookeeper, but I have added the Zookeeper Jar.

```
17/12/11 12:44:10 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.3.1-942149, built on 05/07/2010 17:14 GMT
17/12/11 12:44:10 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:host.name=quickstart.cloudera
17/12/11 12:44:10 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.version=1.8.0_144
17/12/11 12:44:10 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
17/12/11 12:44:10 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.home=/home/cloudera/jdk1.8.0_144/jre
17/12/11 12:44:10 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.class.path=/home/cloudera/workspace/HbaseTbl/bin:/home/cloudera/Downloads/apache-logging-log4j.jar:/home/cloudera/Downloads/hadoop-core-0.20.2-cdh3u0.jar:/home/cloudera/Downloads/hbase-0.94.0.jar:/home/cloudera/Downloads/org-apache-commons-logging.jar:/home/cloudera/Downloads/zookeeper.jar
17/12/11 12:44:10 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
```

Comment: Can you please add the error message you are getting? And also the status of the zookeeper, is its up and running?

Comment: Actually am running this code in Virtual Machine, I got lot of errors about zookeeper.

Comment: And since am creating the Hbase table in the Virtual machine  for testing purpose am adding the required Jars. And not using jars of the project, Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Added the errors in the question itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HBase JAVA API fails creating a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37087667/hbase-java-api-fails-creating-a-table)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code which worked fine for me:

```
        conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        admin = new HBaseAdmin(conf);

        TableName tableName =  TableName.valueOf("test");
        HTableDescriptor htd = new HTableDescriptor(tableName);
        HColumnDescriptor hcd = new HColumnDescriptor("data");

        htd.addFamily(hcd);
        admin.createTable(htd);
```

And also add the following env variables in bash_profile

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/Users/karan.verma/Documents/backups/h/hadoop-2.6.4
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/Users/karan.verma/Documents/backups/h/hadoop-2.6.4
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME

export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar
```

Comment: Can you please provide the Jar files that you have used

Comment: <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
      <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
      <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
      <version>0.95.0</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: My code is not executing after HBaseAdmin admin = new HBaseAdmin( hconfig ); It is throwing many info's regarding zookeeper, as I mentioned in the question. please help me with this.

Comment: It's executing till Configuration hconfig = HBaseConfiguration.create(); HTableDescriptor htable = new HTableDescriptor("User");htable.addFamily( new HColumnDescriptor("Id"));htable.addFamily( new HColumnDescriptor("Name"));System.out.println( "Connecting..." );

Comment: Now am getting an warning like "Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable"

Comment: Am getting the errors like below , like this many errors are coming Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:240)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:218)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:119)

Comment: Have set Java path which is installed in  my system in hbase-env.sh file and Java path is been set correctly in profile path. what else need to done, please help me

Comment: Need one clarification, Do I need to set the path of $HBASE_HOME variable in the profile page?

Comment: Pls check the env variables in the answer

Comment: The thing is we are running our device in standalone mode, is it possible to create the hbase table in this mode or it has to be converted into Psuedomode.

Comment: And since its in standalone mode, no daemons are running and none of the environment variables are set except JAVA(Jdk 1.8). please suggest me how to proceed.

Comment: Also we are using standalone mode, is it possible to achieve Hbase table using Java API or do we need to use psuedo mode.